# Como fazer um loop para gerar gráficos no R?

Tags: r, loop, data.frame, ggplot2, gráfico

Considere o seguinte Data Frame:

```
ITENS <-c("A","B","C","D","E")
Q.1 <-c(10,20,10,40,10)
Q.2 <-c(5,25,0,50,10)
Q.3 <-c(15,20,5,40,10)
Q.4 <-c(15,30,5,30,5)
Q.5 <-c(20,25,5,20,15)
Q.6 <-c(10,20,10,40,10)
df <- data.frame(ITENS,Q.1,Q.2,Q.3,Q.4,Q.5,Q.6)
```

Daí uso o código abaixo para gerar um gráfico:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot.grafico <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$ITENS, y=df$Q.1)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
xlab("Itens") +
ylab("Quantidade de Alunos") +
ggtitle("Titulo")+ guides(fill=FALSE)
plot.grafico
```

Ou seja, é um gráfico em barras da coluna Q.1 do meu data frame. 

**Gostaria de fazer um loop em que eu pudesse gerar o gráfico de cada coluna.** 

Atualmente faço o seguinte:

```
plot.grafico1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$ITENS, y=df$Q.1)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
xlab("Itens") +
ylab("Quantidade de Alunos") +
ggtitle("Titulo")+ guides(fill=FALSE)

plot.grafico2 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$ITENS, y=df$Q.2)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
xlab("Itens") +
ylab("Quantidade de Alunos") +
ggtitle("Titulo")+ guides(fill=FALSE)

plot.grafico3 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$ITENS, y=df$Q.3)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
xlab("Itens") +
ylab("Quantidade de Alunos") +
ggtitle("Titulo")+ guides(fill=FALSE)

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(plot.grafico1,plot.grafico2,plot.grafico3)
```

**Gostaria de uma rotina para não poder repetir o código 6 vezes**

Na verdade o meu data frame original tem 45 colunas.

Comment: O intuito do site não é resolver exercícios e sim tirar dúvidas de programação. Tente colocar o que você já fez e qual a sua dúvida.

Comment: @Phelipe Veja se ficou mais claro depois da edição. Se não puder ajudar, tranquilo ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o loop não é a melhor solução para o seu caso.

```
# alongue o data frame.
library(tidyr)
long <- df %>% gather(turma, quantidade, Q.1:Q.6)

# use facet_wrap
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = ITENS, y = quantidade), stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~turma)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gostei ! Obrigado. De fato não usar o loop pode economizar em tempo de processamento.